# vim - folding with more than one marker

Tags: vim, vi, code-folding

I have a debug file which looks like this:

```
==>func1:
.....
..
==>func2:
......
...
<==func2
..
<==func1
==>func3:
......
...
<==func3
```

Basically, I would like to be able to fold each one of the functions to eventually see something like this:

```
+-- x lines: ==> func1:
+-- x lines: ==> func3:
```

but still be able to expand `func1` and see `func2` folded:

```
==>func1:
.....
..
+-- x lines: ==> func2:
..
<==func1
```

is there any way to do so? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The unmatched markers need extra handle, here's an *expr* solution( see `:h fold-expr`):

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=GetFoldlevel(v:lnum)

function GetFoldlevel(lnum)
    let line = getline(a:lnum)

    let ret = '='
    if line[0:2] == '==>'
        let name = matchstr(line, '^==>\zs\w*')
        let has_match = HasMarkerMatch(a:lnum, name)
        if has_match
            let ret = 'a1'
        endif
    elseif line[0:2] == '<=='
        let ret ='s1'
    endif

    return ret
endfunction

function HasMarkerMatch(lnum, name)
    let endline = line('$')
    let current = a:lnum + 1

    let has_match = 0
    while current <= endline
        let line = getline(current)

        if line =~ '^<=='.a:name
            let has_match = 1
            break
        endif

        let current += 1
    endwhile

    return has_match
endfunction
```

Comment: my problem is that there might be cases where in the debug file, function like for example func4 will have the opening marker but no closing marker and it will destroy the all folding:==>func1: ..... .. ==>func2: ...... ==>func4: ... <==func2 .. <==func1 ==>func3: ...... ... <==func3 . it looks your solution is almost what I need except for the problem that func4 opening marker will be also folded with the closing marker of func2. is there a way to change a bit your solution so to folding will precisely according to the function name?

Comment: Answer is updated to only fold these paired markers.